# TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON\n

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have and endpoint for return just the countDocuments of a schema.
I want to return a JSON object like this

```
{count:3500}
```

But I am getting that error:

```
Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'\n    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'\n    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'\n    --- property 'topology' closes the circle"}}
```

That's my code:

routes.js

```
router.get('/', asyncWrapper(async (req, res) => {  
    const census = await censusService.getCensus();
    return res.send(census);
  }));
```

censusService.js

```
async function getCensus(){
        return await censRepository.getCensus();
    }
```

repository.js

```
async getCensus(){
   
    const { Cens: censSchema } = this.getSchemas();
    const countCensus = censSchema.countDocuments({}, function(err, count) {
      if (err) { return handleError(err) } 
    })
    
    return {
      count: countCensus
    }

  }
```

Comment: Can you add your code on sandbox, pls?

Comment: How I can return just count?